# Корректное отображение ajax сайта в ссылках сообщений или соц. сетях

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

Есть такой проект, www.meteor.com. Они на своих разработках сделали свой основной сайт. По адресу https://www.meteor.com/ в выдаче сервером один код, по https://www.meteor.com/?_escaped_fragment_= другой. Всё как и должно быть в лучших традициях динамических сайтов для поисковиков. Однако, скинув ссылку в мессенджер или соц. сеть на их сайт (https://www.meteor.com/), мы отправляем preview ссылку с уже сформированным заголовком и картинкой (приложу скриншот как это выглядит в imessage, в соц сетях логика та же).[image: imessage]
Как так получается, что страница, на которой установлен [title]Meteor[/title], выдаёт [title]Build Apps with JavaScript | Meteor[/title] в мессенджерах и соц сетях? Не найдя ответа в интернете, я начал копать код их сайта. Зацепок никаких не нашел. После чего я построил аналогичную систему сайты на node js. Так же разделил код на две версии кода. Но толку ноль. В версии mysite.my отдается title - "Загрузка..." . И через js изменяется title на "Главная страница mysite". Так же прописан тег meta name="fragment" content="!". На версии mysite.my/?_escaped_fragment_= Заголовок заранее установлен на "Главная страница mysite". В мессенджерах на ссылку mysite.my выводится заголовок "Загрузка...". Как сделать чтоы выводился заголовок "Главная страница mysite"?

Comment: Не совсем понятно при чем тут метки `javascript ajax node.js`?

Comment: Вам нужен OpenGraph http://ogp.me/